# Characters \$ in echo

Tags: bash

I need to have in a string the text "\$CONDITIONS". I tried used:

```
> echo "\$CONDITIONS"
$CONDITIONS
> echo "\\$CONDITIONS"
\
```

Could you help me? What should I enter in echo command to get

```
\$CONDITIONS
```

as a result?

Comment: echo "\\\$CONDITIONS" is working for me... not for you ?

Comment: `echo '\$CONDITIONS'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\\\` to achieve this.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\\\$CONDITION" # prints \$CONDITION
```

Comment: To be more specific: To print the leading `\ ` use `\\ ` and to print the variable-part `$CONDITION` use `\$CONDITION`.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` doesn't do anything except print exactly the string you pass in.  The trick is to know enough about the shell to be able to pass in the string you want.

If you don't need the shell to perform substitutions on the value, simply use single quotes instead.

```
echo '\$CONDITIONS'
```

If you absolutely need to use double quotes, you can still single-quote individual parts of the string.  Single quotes adjacent to double quotes will get pasted together into a single string before the shell passes it on.

```
echo '\$'"CONDITIONS"
```

Good old `echo` is slightly tired; you might also want to consider `printf` which is somewhat more versatile.

```
printf "\x5c\x24CONDITIONS\n"
```

(I'd normally use single quotes here as well; the double quotes are just to demonstrate that this works even with double quotes. But be careful with the backslashes; these happen to work even with single backslashes, but often they will need to be doubled if you want literal backslashes inside double quotes.)

To review what happened in your failed attempts,

```
echo "\$CONDITIONS"  # produces $CONDITIONS
```

the backslash properly escapes the dollar sign from the shell, and is removed as part of the process.  So you are saying, a literal dollar sign, and the text `CONDITIONS`.

```
echo "\\$CONDITIONS"  # produces \
```

Here, the backslash similarly escapes the backslash, and the shell expands the variable `$CONDITIONS` which is unset or empty.

```
echo "\\\$CONDITIONS"
```

Well, this works, but it's ugly.  There is a backslash-escaped backslash, and a backslash-escaped dollar sign, and the text `CONDITIONS`.

Backslashes and dollar signs (and backticks `` ` ``) don't get processed inside single quotes, so that's what you should usually use if your string contains any of these (and more generally, if you don't specifically require the shell to handle these constructs).

Backslashes are kind of tricky inside double quotes. The shell will remove the ones it processes (so `\$` gets turned into just `$`) but retain the ones it doesn't actually do anything with (so `\x` is preserved as `\x` inside double quotes).   Without quotes, the behavior is different again. (Not even going into that rabbithole. Just use quotes.)